# React-pdf Error when trying to render pdf

Tags: reactjs, react-pdf

I am completely new to ReactJs.

I am trying to create a pdf from html. I want to show the document in the browser and then be able to download it. I am using react-pdf https://react-pdf.org/

I have the code below in which I create my PDF document and then I want to display my document with PDFViewer. This page is not my main "App" page - it is a "Client details" page to which I can navigate.

When I run this I get the following error:

> TypeError: Failed to construct 'Text': Please use the 'new' operator, this DOM object constructor cannot be called as a function.

The error is here: renderWithHooks
*C:/Users/Marileen/Downloads/react-material-dashboard-master (1)/react-material-dashboard-master/node_modules/@react-pdf/renderer/node_modules/react-reconciler/cjs/react-reconciler.development.js:5671* with line `5671 var children = Component(props, refOrContext);`

```
import React from "react";
import { PDFViewer } from '@react-pdf/renderer';
import { Document, Page, View } from '@react-pdf/renderer';

const PdfDocument = () => (
    <Document>
        <Page size="A4">
            <View>
                <Text>Section #1</Text>
            </View>
        </Page>
    </Document>
);

const ClientDetails = () => {
    return (<PDFViewer>
        <PdfDocument />
    </PDFViewer>);
}
export default ClientDetails;
```

I have tried different libraries, I've installed babel, but I don't understand how to fix the problem in Reactjs.

Please help?

Comment: Error is in `<Text>`. Where are you importing it from?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After checking out the docs of react-pdf it seems like you haven't imported `Text` from it's library and you are using it in your component.

That's why error is thrown when you use text without importing it in this line -

```
<Text>Section #1</Text>
```

Change your -

```
import { Document, Page, View } from '@react-pdf/renderer'; //add Text here//
```

to -

```
import { Document, Page, View, Text } from '@react-pdf/renderer';
```

Answer (score -1):

I might be a little late on that but I've found a recent solution like bellow:

```js
import React from 'react';
import {Document, Page, pdfjs} from 'react-pdf';
import "react-pdf/dist/esm/Page/AnnotationLayer.css" // Blocks blank TextLayers.

pdfjs.GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc = `//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdf.js/${pdfjs.version}/pdf.worker.js`; // Fix your issue.

function PdfFileReader() {
  const yourFileUrl_Or_Base64 = 'https://www.orimi.com/pdf-test.pdf'
  
  return(
    <Document
      file={yourFileUrl_Or_Base64}
    >
      <Page
        pageNumber={pages}
        renderTextLayer={false} // Blocks blank TextLayer
      />
    </Document>
  )
}
```

Comment: Not sure if you mixed something up here, but react-pdf and @react-pdf/renderer are not the same thing.